# Azure hosting from Pycharm

Tags: django, azure, pycharm, publish

I want to try and push my django app to Azure, has anyone done this? I am using MySQL for the database but can only find POSTGRESQL as a WebApp. Does anyone have any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

yeah, search for mysql and you will find it:

[image]